How to map Map<String, Map<String, String>> from application.yml in micronaut
I have some configuration in my application.yml as below
  nested:
    property1:
      key1: value1
      key2: value2
    property2:
      keyA: valueA
      keyB: valueB

Here i give a input like
input1: property1
input2: key2
output: value
I am trying to map this into Map<String, Map<String, String>> nested so that i can do nested.get("input1").get("input2") to get my output
I tried below but no luck. Any help would be appreciated
public class Props {
    @Property(name = "nested")
    @MapFormat(keyFormat = StringConvention.RAW)
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> nested = new HashMap<>();
}


You can try @ConfigurationProperties annotation

already tried that it didn't help with the above config i am able to atleast map property1 and property2 into my nested map
